# Missing template application_mailer/mailer with "mailer". Searched in: * "application_mailer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer, scaffold

i have to develop a mailer using ruby on rails and i keep getting that error, I don't know how to correct it, I have tried a lot of methods. This is my code

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  layout 'application_mailer'

  def mailer(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Welcome"
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have `mailer.html.erb` in any of app folders?

Comment: in views/layout

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace in the question?

Comment: That is the full error i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `mailer.html.erb`
 under `app/views/application_mailers`

mailer action need view to render so it is searching for application_mailers/mailer.html.erb which is missing I think

Comment: i have one in views/layout, I have to make another in app/mailer?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello <%= @user.email %> </h1>
  </body>
</html>
That is the code i have in the .html.erb

Comment: That is your application_mailer layout file but you need another one app/views/application_mailers/mailer.html.erb

Comment: I also have one with this code. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <h1>Hello <%= @user.email %> </h1>
  </body>
</html>